# Store different cache value for every user in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

```
Cache.Insert("City", UserCity,
             null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
             new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0));
```

I want save cache for 24 hours for a particular user but whenever i open the page the same cache details are shown for all users. How do i differentiate for every user?

Comment: Consider using Session not cache.

Comment: Cache isn't a bad idea, but cache should be used to store the basic site data like CSS files and other stuff! Like html, that has to run everytime like the Layout.

Comment: i think best thing to do is using cookies or browser data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring considerations of whether or not it's a good idea, you can do this by including something that uniquely identifies the user, such as the userName, in the cache key:

```
string key = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "-City";
Cache.Insert(key,...)
```

Putting user-specific data in the Cache is not scalable if you can have large numbers of users, but there may be some cases where it's appropriate.  For example, it would be reasonable for a custom `RoleProvider` used in an Intranet application with a known upper limit on the number of concurrent users to store user-specific roles in Cache.